# Derivative in normed space

Tags: limits, normed-spaces, differential-topology, vector-analysis

I'm studying the Differential Calculus Functions of several variables. Let $f:A\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable with $||f(t)||>0$ for all $t\in A$. Prove that: $$u(t)=\dfrac{f(t)}{||f(t)||}$$ is differentiable and find $<u(t),u'(t)>$

I know the way to check $u(t)$ is differentiable or not that is calculating this limit: $$\lim\limits_{h\to0}{\dfrac{||u(t+h)-u(t)||}{|h|}};$$
And what I got next is: $$\lim\limits_{h\to0}{\dfrac{\bigg|\bigg|\dfrac{f(t+h)}{||f(t+h)||}-\dfrac{f(t)}{||f(t)||}\bigg|\bigg|}{|h|}}$$
I found out that:
$$\dfrac{\bigg|\bigg|\dfrac{f(t+h)}{||f(t+h)||}-\dfrac{f(t)}{||f(t)||}\bigg|\bigg|}{|h|}\le\dfrac{1}{|h|}\bigg|\bigg|\dfrac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{||f(t+h)||}+\left(\dfrac{1}{||f(t+h)||}-\dfrac{1}{||f(t)||}\right)f(t)\bigg|\bigg|$$
$$\le\dfrac{1}{||f(t+h)||}\dfrac{||f(t+h)-f(t)||}{|h|}+\dfrac{1}{|h|}\bigg|\dfrac{1}{||f(t+h)||}-\dfrac{1}{||f(t)||}\bigg|||f(t)||;$$
Let $|h|\to0$ then: $$\lim\limits_{h\to0}{\dfrac{||u(t+h)-u(t)||}{|h|}}\le2\dfrac{||f'(t)||}{||f(t)||}$$ but I see it's not useful to my problem. Please help me.

Comment: The function $\|f(t)\|^{-1}$ is differentiable. So the function $u(t)$ is differentiable as well.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I haven't known that. Can you explain why ?

Comment: You have $f(t)=(f_1(t),\ldots, f_n(t))$ and each function $f_j$ is differentiable. So is $\|f(t)\|=\sqrt{f_1^2+\ldots +f_n^2}.$ Then $\|f(t)\|^{-1}$ is differentiable as $\|f(t)\|>0.$

Comment: Because every function $\|f(t)\|^{-1}f_j(t)$ is differentiable.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc okay I will check carefully again. Thank you for help.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc by the way, is $u'=\dfrac{f'}{||f||}$ ?

Comment: Do not use `||` for norms.  Either use `\lVert` and `\rVert` (if you are fancy and want the spacing to be entirely correct) or `\|` (if you are in a hurry, and are willing to accept a little bit of slop sometimes).

Answer (score 3):

The function $u$ is differentiable as a ratio of differentiable functions $f$ and $|f\|.$  We have $1=\|u(t)\|^2=\langle u(t),u(t)\rangle.$ Thus $$ 0={d\over dt}\langle u(t),u(t)\rangle=2\langle u(t),u'(t)\rangle.$$
**Remark** There is no need for calculating $u'.$

Answer (score 1):

The $i$-th component of $u(t)$ is
$$u_i(t)=(f_1^2(t)+\ldots+f_n^2(t))^{-\frac{1}{2}}f_i(t)$$

Using the product rule, you find
$$
\begin{aligned}
u_i'(t)&=-\frac{1}{2}(f_1^2(t)+\ldots+f_n^2(t))^{-\frac{3}{2}} 2(f_1(t)f_1'(t)+\ldots+f_n(t)f_n'(t))f_i(t)\\
&\quad+(f_1^2(t)+\ldots+f_n^2(t))^{-\frac{1}{2}}f_i'(t)\\
&=-\frac{\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle}{\lVert f(t)\rVert^3}f_i(t)+\frac{1}{\lVert f(t)\rVert}f_i'(t),
\end{aligned}$$

such that

$$u'(t)=-\frac{\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle}{\lVert f(t)\rVert^3}f(t)+\frac{f'(t)}{\lVert f(t)\rVert}.$$

This yields

$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle u(t),u'(t)\rangle 
&= \langle \frac{f(t)}{\lVert f(t) \rVert},-\frac{\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle}{\lVert f(t)\rVert^3}f(t)+\frac{f'(t)}{\lVert f(t)\rVert}\rangle\\
&= \langle \frac{f(t)}{\lVert f(t) \rVert},-\frac{\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle}{\lVert f(t)\rVert^3}f(t)\rangle + \langle \frac{f(t)}{\lVert f(t) \rVert},\frac{f'(t)}{\lVert f(t)\rVert}\rangle\\
&=-\frac{\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle}{\lVert f(t)\rVert^4}\langle f(t),f(t)\rangle+\frac{1}{\lVert f(t) \rVert^2}\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle\\
&=-\frac{\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle}{\lVert f(t)\rVert^2}+\frac{\langle f(t),f'(t)\rangle}{\lVert f(t)\rVert^2}\\
&=0.
\end{aligned}$$